# String class constructor and copy constructor

Tags: c++, string, constructor, copy-constructor

I'm building a String class, and I was wondering if in the constructor and the copy constructor I should copy the characters or just point to the same memory address as the passed char* / the char* of the copied String object ? 
This is what I wrote so far :

```
String::String(const char* pch)
{
    str = const_cast<char*>(pch);
    length = getLen();
}

String::String(const String& that)
{
    length = that.length;
    str = new char[length];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        str[i] = that.str[i];
    }
}
```

In the constructor I'm just pointing to the same address as the const char*, should I leave it as that or copy each character into a new allocated memory block ? If I were to change the string I would allocated a new memory block anyway so the char* being const isn't much of a big deal (I think). In the copy constructor I copied each character to a new allocated memory space but I'm not sure it's necessary because if I would change the string later a new memory block will be allocated for the object that is changing leaving the other object with the same pointer untouched.
Wanted to hear you opinions.
"str" is of type char*.

Comment: (1) Why not use `std::string`? (2) Always copy; string should be a "value" class. (3) You have *no idea* who owns the pointer that is passed in, nor when the string it points to could be deallocated. It is **unsafe** to retain a copy of the pointer!

Comment: @cdhowie homework this is why :) and thanks didn't thought of the case that the memory will be deallocated.

Comment: @cdhowie forgot to ask, in the constructo the paramater is passed is const char*, if I were to create const char* I wouldn't be able to deallocate it because it's not being created with memory allocation functions so it won't be deallocated no ? so is it ok to leave it as is (talking about the constructor)

Comment: @Tugal.44 This won't work. You'll always need to allocate your internal buffer with `new char[](x)` (and don't forget to `delete []` it accordingly of course). You can't mix that with simple pointer assignments as done in your other constructor.

Comment: You don't know the origin of the pointer, what if you store the address of a stack object that gets destroyed and later you try to read it?

Comment: Ok got it. so my copy constructor is fine right ? Also if I would like to overload the = operator, is there a good way to do it ? What I would do is do the same thing as the copy constructor does but use delete[] before that and return *This at the end, but that looks to me like a redundant code because most of it is in the copy constructor already

Comment: In your first case, what happens if someone modifies the string which points to a string literal?

Comment: @NeilKirk but if someone modifies it a new memory block will be allocated for it so the size will be just enough to hold it

Comment: @Tugal.44 Don't forget that you have to delete in the assignment operator as well as in the destructor.  _And_ that you shouldn't delete until after you've allocated the new block, since the allocation may fail.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have control over the lifetime of the string whose pointer is passed to the constructor, it's unsafe to rely on it. Make a copy of the string.

Also since you don't know if the passed pointer was `const` or not, casting away constness as you do can lead to undefined behavior.